# Jquery Slide Toggle : Slide Button with Panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on jquery slide tab and its working fine on button click. But I want that button stitch with panel and also should slide with panel. currently button is fix and panel working as expected.

Here Is **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/S38AH/)**

**HTML**

```
    <button id="showmenu" type="button" class="feed_btn">Feed Back</button>         
<div class="sidebarmenu">
                  <div class="slide-out-div" style="z-index: 999;">
                      <form  class="generalForm bookingForm" action="#" method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <label>Name<span>*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" name="Name" class="required" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 mar_top">
                            <label>Email <span>*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" name="Email" class="required" />

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 mar_top">
                            <label>Contact No <span>*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" name="contact_no" class="required" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 mar_top">
                            <label>Say Few Words<span>*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" name="feedback" class="required" />

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="background-image:none; padding-left:20px;" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                 </div>


            </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .sidebarmenu{
        position:absolute;
        right:-250px;
        z-index:999999;
    }
```

**JS**

```
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
        var hidden = $('.sidebarmenu').data('hidden');

        if(hidden){
            $('.sidebarmenu').animate({
                right: '-250px'
            },500)

        } else {
            $('.sidebarmenu').animate({
                right: '0px'
            },500)
        }
        $('.sidebarmenu,.image').data("hidden", !hidden);

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As want to move button along with form, then you need add one parent and move that only instead form **[see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S38AH/2/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel">
    <button id="showmenu" type="button" class="feed_btn">Feed Back</button>
    <div class="sidebarmenu"> -- your code --</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#showmenu').click(function () {
    var hidden = $('.sidebarmenu').data('hidden');

    if (hidden) {
        $('.panel').animate({
            marginRight: '-250px'
        }, 500)

    } else {
        $('.panel').animate({
            marginRight: '0px'
        }, 500)
    }
    $('.sidebarmenu,.image').data("hidden", !hidden);

});
```

Comment: hmm, I do, but we can't accept for first 5 min. :) but now all ok